# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Remove Identity Pages created using Scaffolding

Tags: asp.net-core, customization, scaffolding, asp.net-core-identity

I'm probably just missing a simple trick here, but I created the Identity framework in an ASP.NET Core project, created my own fields with my own classes, ran migrations, then once confirmed it was all working with the Default UI. It was working perfectly so went to customize the Identity UI so I could better control specific pages. Trouble was, thought I'd be adventurous and select every page to customize... yes dumb I know.. Now I've got some 80 pages or something that I no longer want.

I really only want to scaffold the registration and manage data pages, if I ran the Scaffolding again will that simply create new pages or fail because the pages already exist, or will it remove any pages that I don't select? I'm loathed to try it for fear of breaking something.

Perhaps it's down to manually deleting the pages I don't want, but will that cause issues with those pages that I haven't selected to customize. Seems great there's a scaffolding option to create the pages, but removing them... it's not so obvious...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For removing unwanted Identity Pages, you could delete them directly from your solution.

For `Identity Razor page`, if you add scaffold pages or manually create the razor pages with the corresponding name in `Identity/Pages/Account`, they will replace default Identity Razor page implementation. If there is no razor pages or you delete them, it will reuse default razor page from `Razor library`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!